# remove entry from XTS object and update the following evaluation for Exponential Moving Average

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have a xts and I calculate the EMA. I want to compare the i value with previous EMA and if above a threshold, remove that point and subsequently update the EMA evaluation.

Something like:

```
dat<-as.xts(data)
dat_EMA<-EMA(abs(dat),n=10)
dat_EMA<-lag(dat_EMA,k=-1)
```

Then, if `dat > 100*dat_EMA`, remove from `dat` that point and recalculate the following part of EMA.

Is there any effective procedure?

Comment: You would have to write your own custom EMA function from scratch.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich :so, let's split the question:1) how to remove a single entry from an XTS object?  2)(Since I realize that you are the author :-) ) is it possible to have the code of the original EMA function? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Edit: don't worry for the second question, I found the C code, but the first remains open.

Comment: Just carry the last observation forward one period.  Removing it would be odd because then the function would return an object shorter than the input.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: thanks for the suggestion, I agree, in this case it's more effective. For future purposes: is there a way to remove a single entry in xts?

Comment: Exactly the same way you do it with a matrix: `x <- x[-1,]`.

Comment: Thanks! Last question :-) A good starting point (I'm a newbie) for including my own C version of EMA in R?